# MySQL : Multiple SELECT and OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm quite new with MySQL, and having trouble arranging some tables, I can't seem to find a solution anywhere...

To simplify, say I have two types of tables, a and b, the first in 3 pieces and the second in 2 pieces. So a1, a2, a3 that I want to merge with b1, b2 by the first column.

To join a1 and b1 I do :

```
SELECT a.column1, a.column2
FROM table_a1 AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b1 AS b ON (a.column1=b.column1)
```

Now how can I select from a1, a2, a3 and join with b1, b2 ?

Comment: What are your foreign and primary keys? There could be quite a few ways to do this without knowing the specifics.

Comment: Can you give table structures with example data? It will be better if you use sqlfiddle.com

Comment: What do you mean by 'merge'?

Comment: The first column is primary key in the tables a, but not in the tables b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the design might need some work.

But for now, you can do this:

```
SELECT 
  a.column1, a.column2
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM table_a1
   UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_a2
   UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_a3) AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM table_b1
   UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_b2) AS b
ON (a.column1 = b.column1)
```

Comment: Some of my tables do not have the same number of columns so it doesn't work... should have mentionned it from the start, sorry.
Thanks for the help though

Comment: Oh it works if I select data correctly of course.
Seems to do the trick, I'll implement it fully and get back with a definitive confirmation.

Comment: Yep it works great ! Thanks a lot to all of you guys you're awesome !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want something as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a1 a
LEFT JOIN table_b1 b ON b.column1 = a.column1
```

But Golez there has a totally different answer, which makes me think I've read the question wrong =/

Comment: Yeah, in fact my problem is that the data is spread on several different tables... It's a headache for a newbie like me^^
Thanks anyway for your answer